# PHP 5.4.12 Mac OSX imagecreate* functions not working

Tags: php, apache, gd, macports, imagecreatefrompng

I am running PHP 5.4.12 from macports on Mac OSX 10.7.5 with Apache 2 (Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 PHP/5.4.12).  5 days ago this code worked (yes directly from PHP site):

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im); 
?>
```

I closed my laptop.  Then opened it 3 days later, went to my test page with this code, and it no longer worked but I get no errors.  I see the broken image image instead of the generated image.  I upgraded all my software and libs today.  This is what phpinfo says about GD Lib:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.10
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version unknown
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.5.14
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

phpinfo() reports this about my php install:

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/opt/local' '--mandir=/opt/local/share/man' 
'--infodir=/opt/local/share/info' '--program-suffix=54' 
'--includedir=/opt/local/include/php54' '--libdir=/opt/local/lib/php54' 
'--with-config-file-path=/opt/local/etc/php54' 
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/local/var/db/php54' '--disable-all' '--enable-bcmath' 
'--enable-ctype' '--enable-dom' '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-filter' '--enable-hash' 
'--enable-json' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-phar' '--enable-session' 
'--enable-simplexml' '--enable-tokenizer' '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader' 
'--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-bz2=/opt/local' '--with-mhash=/opt/local' 
'--with-pcre-regex=/opt/local' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/local' '--with-zlib=/opt/local' 
'--without-pear' '--disable-cgi' '--disable-cli' '--disable-fpm' 
'--with-apxs2=/opt/local/apache2/bin/apxs'
```

I notice there's no '--with-gd' in there, but I made no changes to PHP between this code working and breaking...

It is entirely possible that when I closed my laptop and then reopened, apache restarted.  I did not install or upgrade anything (made absolutely no changes to php) or make any changes to any ini files or upgrade anything in the recent past. Today, however, I did do a full upgrade of everything installed using macports.  Didn't fix the problem.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem/finding solutions?

Comment: update:  i tested this changing: imagepng($im);  to:  imagepng($im,'myimg.png'); and ran it from the command line.  the image was created.  i'm trying to establish why it's not working from the browser now.

Comment: cli used different php.ini.  php.ini for website is specific to the site and includes an auto prepend file - which includes several other files - one of which had extra lines at the end of the file - i'd edited the file just before closing my laptop a week ago.  so, before the header() function was called, output had already begun.  thus the breakage.  hope this post helps someone else save a days worth of work someday.